# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA2 + Hibernate web project and I would like to test if it persists.

This is the entity:

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity(name="alunos")
public class Aluno {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   private String nome;


   public void setId(Long id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public String getNome() {
       return nome;
   }

   public void setNome(String nome) {
       this.nome = nome;
   }
}
```

This is the `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="PrimeiroProjetoJSF" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <class>model.Aluno</class>

        <properties>


            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@------------"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="-----"/> 
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="------"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" /> 

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

This is the class with a `main()` method to test the persistence:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import model.Aluno;


public class GeraTabelas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PrimeiroProjetoJSF");
        EntityManager fac = factory.createEntityManager();

        Aluno arthur = new Aluno();
        arthur.setNome("Arthur");
        fac.persist(arthur);
        factory.close();

    }
}
```

When I run it, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory 
       at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81) at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at GeraTabelas.main(GeraTabelas.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactory>uilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:73)
    ... 4 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Where is your ` hibernate.cfg.xml` - I'm guessing there is a problem in that since it looks like a JDBC configuration problem.

Comment: Well I'm using persistence.xml instead of hibernate.cfg.xml, is that even possible ?

Comment: Sure, but how does it look :)

Comment: I found my mistake. It was a class marked as @Entity but not declared on persistence.xml. Not only this, a library was missing too. I replaced the all pack of libs with a working one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. It was another class marked as @Entity but not declared on persistence.xml. Not only this, a library was missing too. I replaced the all pack of libs with a working one

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when MySQL was not running. Starting MySQL solved it.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it was an issue with the DB server address. In 20 years I have never seen more obscure and misleading error messages as in Grails / Spring / Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone googling this exception:

```
Exception during lifecycle processing 
java.lang.NullPointerException         
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:244)
```

It is the Exception I see when our database server is restarted and I have forgotten to configure the application server connection pool to automatically detect stale connections and re-obtain them.   In other words if your database server is restarted you either must restart your application server or flush the connection pool.  Flushing the connection pool can be automated in GlassFish for example by configuring connection validation with the option to close all connections when a connection doesn't validate.   A simple table validation method for Oracle is to query SYS.DUAL.